# baked texture is different from the preview in shading

Tags: texture-baking, shader-nodes

Tried to bake texture with cycle. But the baking result is pretty bad. Not sure whether the mesh caused some parts of problems. I am still learning modelling. And there are also some wired shadows in shading peview.[image]
[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TBWn8MZFo6F2AQJvdbZJ27bfcgGZTsnI/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate of your hat mesh that is hidden from viewport but visible for rendering (and thus also used when baking). Simply hide your object for rendering, and your texture should be alright as seen below :

[image: Hide object from rendering]

Comment: I thought my mesh or uv unwarp has some problems. Didn't expect caused by this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Blender 4.0? if yes set the samples around 1000 for better quality
or try using a different image size

Comment: I took the liberty to downvote. The blend file is provided, apparently you didn't test your answer + if you have questions, the comments would be the better place to ask them. I hope I don't discourage you by doing so, but instead build together a high quality stack exchange.